# How to get data (text and pictures) from server via http get request with NFC tools?

Tags: android, httprequest, nfc

On my Android phone I use NFC Tools pro and I want to do following:

- get text from my server (i.e. to show it in a popup or text-to-speech)
- get picture from my server and show it

I found the "HTTP GET" request task but couldn't find out, how to use it.
(It is similar to following post/request: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=21b5d890966b165096d73b83bd07cd9a&p=57083540&postcount=41).

I also can show pictures, but only those which are located on the local phone.

Comment: if it's not related to developement, you better ask to Android Enthousiast

Comment: ok, I've asked this at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129968/how-to-get-data-text-and-pictures-from-server-via-http-get-request-using-a-nfc. Nevertheless there is a bit programming, when creating the response on my server. ;)

Comment: but it's related to the "web" more than Android. You need to clarify what you are trying to do on your server